# Timeline of rendering techniques?

Tags: graphics, 3d, rendering

I'm looking for a historical overview of computer graphics developments, a timeline of such things as

- bump mapping
- bloom
- stencil buffer shadows
- volumetric fog
- subsurface scattering
- radiosity
- etc, the more inclusive the better

according to when they were invented and when they became practical for real-time mainstream use.

Hopefully this research would include an analysis of how much the end result has been improved by the invention of **new** techniques versus **better** algorithms for old techniques versus simply applying them more **extensively** given improving hardware.

Got any links for this sort of thing? Thanks.

Comment: As written, this question asks for an off-site resource.  If that question is edited out, the question is too broad, as a good answer would constitute an entire survey article on the history of rendering.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the Wikipedia article on [Rendering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rendering_%28computer_graphics%29)? It has a list o influential articles on the subject, and their years of publication.